# Problem with Windows Boot Manager/BIOS in dual boot

Tags: grub2, uefi, lenovo, windows-10, bootloader

PC model- Lenovo Ideapad 300
OS- Windows 10 dual booted with Ubuntu 18.04

I am not able to start windows or view grub menu or  see Lenovo logo(which was visible earlier) after one fine day I put my Windows to sleep. Sleep mode was working perfectly fine earlier.
Now only Ubuntu 18.04 is starting and grub menu is not visible, also windows is not able to start properly. The display is black until Ubuntu loads.
How can I recover windows and bios.
When grub is updated in terminal it successfully detects all OS.

Comment: have you tried the boot repair disk? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. Or Windows that is not hibernated nor needs chkdsk. If UEFI, you can boot Windows  directly from UEFI boot menu.  Note that Windows turns fast start up back on with updates, so if grub does not work directly boot Windows and turn it off again. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions
More explanation of NTFS driver & Windows hibernation
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/32WmszmhWj/ the boot repair log file after disabling srcure boot

Answer (score 0):

Most boot/dual boot issues can be fixed with the awesome Boot Repair utility:

[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Make yourself a boot repair disk, boot it and run the Recommended Repair utility.

Comment: Kindly view the boot info file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18hli-d13WGoYb_h56oc26kystwaCg-wf/view?usp=sharing) . here it says that no bootloader is installed. What can I do next?

Comment: I think that was the problem that it found... did you remove the boot repair disk and reboot?

Comment: Yes, but no progress, the screen is still blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the grub boot manager timeout so that you get a change to select the OS on startup. To do this, boot into Ubuntu and then edit the following file.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Modify the line with `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to something like

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=30
```

After that you need to update the grub setup in your boot manager

```
sudo update-grub
```

You should now be able to select your Ubuntu or Windows OS in the boot manager menu.

Comment: Kindly view the boot info file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18hli-d13WGoYb_h56oc26kystwaCg-wf/view?usp=sharing) . here it says that no bootloader is installed. What can I do next?

Comment: grub is not displaying nor is the lenovo logo during boot(used to display earlier), the screen remained blank if I forced windows to boot

Comment: @NITISHBAHL There should not be a bootloader installed in the MBR, you are using EFI booting. The Ubuntu EFI is shown to be installed in sda1. `grubx64.efi` will be loaded by the BIOS, not bootloader in MBR.